# How to customize options to get full country name as value of country_select gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have used **[country_select](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select)** gem, it working fine, now I want to set option value as full country name same as what it displayed in dropdown, not contry code.

for eg: I am getting like below:

```
<select id="order_ship_country" name="order[ship_country]">
    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
</select>
```

But I am expecting like this:

```
<select id="order_ship_country" name="order[ship_country]">
    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the point to do that? You already have full country name in `option` body...

Comment: @nattfodd : I guess OP want full country name as value to store into DB

Answer (score 1):

1/ Make an initializer

```rb
# config/initializers/country_select.rb

CountrySelect::FORMATS[:with_full_country_name] = lambda do |country|
  [
    country.name,
    country.alpha2,
    {
      'value' => country.name,
    }
  ]
end
```

2/ Call it in your view with `format`

```
<%= country_select("user", "country", format: :with_full_country_name) %>
```

As explained in the documentation : https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select#using-a-custom-formatter

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in the `User` model, as explained from [their doc](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select#iso-3166-1-alpha-2-codes), you create an instance method called `country_name`, that will return the `country name` of that user. Also remember to replace `country_code` with the attribute of your `User` model, that you are using to store that country code.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Assuming country_select is used with User attribute `country_code`
  # This will attempt to translate the country name and use the default
  # (usually English) name if no translation is available
    def country_name
      country = ISO3166::Country[country_code]
      country.translations[I18n.locale.to_s] || country.name
    end
end
```

then you use the [`select` form helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html)

```
select("user", "country_code", User.all.collect {|u| [ u.country_name, u.country_code ] })
```

this should generate

```
<select name="user[country_code]" id="user_country_code">
  <option value="AF">Africa</option>
  <option value="IT">Italy</option>
  <option value="FR">France</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The ISO country translation is exactly what I needed - Thank You!